# How to set icon over current playing song from listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

Hi i have listview with list of songs. i want to draw small icon over current song playing & remove from when next song start playing & set to that song.
Any help code snippet would be appericiated

Comment: Have you tried anything so far before posting this question?

Comment: It is easy. Make a little effort and google android custom listview

Comment: i have created custom listview but i want to change single row element in listview

Comment: @Jags In that case you should have posted your code to make ppl wanna help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add icon to your listview make it invisible first then write code in java

```
if(SongIndex !=position){
Image.setvisibility(View.Invisible)
}
else{
Image.setvisibility(View.Visible)
}
notifydatasetchanged();
```