# I want to draw small icon over current song playing. Listview not updating new changes when using notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, media-player

Hi I developed Media Player which plays songs from raw files. I have listview with list of songs.  I am able to draw small icon over current song playing, but the icon disappears when I scroll through the listview up to the top or down to the bottom.
I want the small icon to stay on the playing song & to be removed from the current song when next song start playing & set to the new song.

Evrything is working fine but the Listview not updated.

This is the Adapter

```
public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private int[] iconImage;
    private String[] indexText;
    private String[] englishText;


    private LayoutInflater myInflater;


    //Constructor
    public SongAdapter(Context c, String[] aIndexText, String[] aEnglishText, 
                       int[] aIconImage) {

        iconImage = aIconImage;
        indexText = aIndexText;
        englishText = aEnglishText;
        myInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return englishText.length;
    }




    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return indexText[position] + " " + englishText[position];
    }

   @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View myView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_detail_layout, null);

        ImageView iconImageView = myView.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
        TextView indexTextView = myView.findViewById(R.id.IndexTextView);
        TextView englishTextView = myView.findViewById(R.id.englishTextView);


        iconImageView.setImageResource(iconImage[position]);
        indexTextView.setText(indexText[position]);
        englishTextView.setText(englishText[position]);

        //Make all icons invisible
        iconImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        return myView;
    }
}
```

This is the MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
        private SongAdapter mySongAdapter;
        private Field[] fields;
        private MediaPlayer mp;
        private ListView lv;


        private ArrayList<String> myArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

        private Button btnPlay;
        private Button btnNxt;
        private Button btnRep;
        private Button btnShuf;
        private Button btnAto;
        private TextView elapsedTimeLabel;
        private TextView remainingTimeLabel;
        private SeekBar seekBar = null;
        private int resId = 0;
        private int position = 0;
        private int newPosition = 0;
        private Toast toast;
        private TextView titleTextView;
        private Boolean shuffle = false; 
        private Boolean paused = false;
        private Boolean isAuto = false; 
        private volatile Boolean stopThread = false;
        private Random rand = new Random();


        private ImageView indexImageView;





        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            try {

                lv = findViewById(R.id.songsListView);

                int[] iconImage = {R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp,
                        R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp
                };

                String[] indexText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.indexText);
                String[] englishText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.englishText);

                seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

                btnPlay = findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
                btnNxt = findViewById(R.id.btnNxt);
                Button btnPv = findViewById(R.id.btnPv);
                Button btnFF = findViewById(R.id.btnFF);
                Button btnFB = findViewById(R.id.btnFB);
                btnRep = findViewById(R.id.btnRep);
                btnShuf = findViewById(R.id.btnShuf);
                btnAto = findViewById(R.id.btnAuto);

                elapsedTimeLabel = findViewById(R.id.elapsedTimeLabel);
                remainingTimeLabel = findViewById(R.id.remainingTimeLabel);
                titleTextView = findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);

                indexImageView = findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);




                mySongAdapter = new SongAdapter(this, indexText, englishText, iconImage);

                lv.setAdapter(mySongAdapter);

            }catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    try {

                        if (resId == position) {
                            view.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            view.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                        mySongAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
                        lv.isScrollingCacheEnabled();
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Actually I want to implement this solution which I found Here [How to set icon over current playing song from listview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187380/how-to-set-icon-over-current-playing-song-from-listview-in-android)

Add icon to your listview make it invisible first then write code in java

```
if(SongIndex !=position){
Image.setvisibility(View.Invisible)
}
else{
Image.setvisibility(View.Visible)
}
notifydatasetchanged();
```

I think I did all of that but I have problem when calling  notifydatasetchanged(); the listview is not updating.

Thanks alot in advance for any help or any partecipation from anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use *RecyclerView* instead of *ListView* and use only one *ArrayList* with the custom object of all of your entities like this.

```
public class Song {
private int imageIcon;
private String indexText;
private String englishText;
private String arabicText;


public Song(int imageIcon, String indexText, String englishText, String arabicText) {
    this.imageIcon = imageIcon;
    this.indexText = indexText;
    this.englishText = englishText;
    this.arabicText = arabicText;
}

public int getImageIcon() {
    return imageIcon;
}

public void setImageIcon(int imageIcon) {
    this.imageIcon = imageIcon;
}

public String getIndexText() {
    return indexText;
}

public void setIndexText(String indexText) {
    this.indexText = indexText;
}

public String getEnglishText() {
    return englishText;
}

public void setEnglishText(String englishText) {
    this.englishText = englishText;
}

public String getArabicText() {
    return arabicText;
}

public void setArabicText(String arabicText) {
    this.arabicText = arabicText;
} }
```

Use this data source like this.

> ArrayList songs= new ArrayList();

In Recyclerview there are 2 common methods to update the view .

1. notifyDataSetChanged() to update all the list.
2. notifyItemChaged(int postion) to update specific item

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but let's try to find solution using the listview.

Comment: Do you know how to implement it using listview?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can create a `model class` for each song item. Like

```
public class Song(){
  public String songUrl.
  public boolean isPlaying;
  // rest of your item
}
```

So when you playing song change the current `Song` model `isPlaying = true`.

And call `notifyItemChange(positon);` and **remember** you have to call two `notifiItemChange(positon)`

One for the previous item that is currently playing.
Second for the item that you want to play.

For the  first item you have to set `isPlaying = false` and call `notifiItemChange(currentPlayingItemPosition)`

For the second item that you want to play now set `isPlaying = true` and call `notifiItemChange(newSongItemPosition)`

And in your adapter, you can get a call that your current item is changed and from `isPlaying` option you can decide that which icon will show or not.

I hope you can get a good idea from this answer.

Comment: Do you mean creating class for each and evry song?

Comment: It means you have to create a new **object** for each song. And finally, you will get a List<Song> items

Comment: And in your adapter, you can get a call that your current item is changed. How?

Comment: When you call notifiItemChange(position) you can get call in onBind() .

Comment: Actually I want to implement this solution which I found Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187380/how-to-set-icon-over-current-playing-song-from-listview-in-android


Add icon to your listview make it invisible first then write code in java
if(SongIndex !=position){
Image.setvisibility(View.Invisible)
}
else{
Image.setvisibility(View.Visible)
}
notifydatasetchanged();

Comment: I did all that but I think I have a problem when calling notifydatasetchanged();

Comment: you have to call `notifiItemChange(position)` insteadOf   `notifydatasetchanged()`; . When you click an item from adapter you can get that's item position from adapter.

Note: `notifiItemChange(position)`  refresh current item whereas `notifydatasetchanged()` all item

Comment: You can find it: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter